# Synchronize nested async task

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I have nested async tasks. The function below following this flow: loadEpisodes(load a list of episodes) -> use a array from completion to loop through each episode one and load comments ( one more async task ) for specific episode.

The problem is: comletion(fullyEpisodes) excuted before finishing comments load task. I tried to use Dispatch Group (second code block) but it's not working.

```
func loadComments(comletion: @escaping ([Episode]) -> Void){
loadEpisodes(completion: {
    episodes in
    var fullyEpisodes = [Episode]()
    for episode in episodes {
        WebService().load(resource: episode.comment, comletion: {
            comments in
            if let comments = comments {
                let _episode = Episode(id: episode.id, title: episode.title, comments: comments)
                fullyEpisodes.append(_episode)
                print("done")
            }
        })
    }
    comletion(fullyEpisodes)

})
}
```

Implemented Dispatch Group:

```
func loadComments(comletion: @escaping ([Episode]) -> Void){
    loadEpisodes(completion: {
        episodes in
        var fullyEpisodes = [Episode]()
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        for episode in episodes {
            group.enter()
            WebService().load(resource: episode.comment, comletion: {
                comments in
                if let comments = comments {
                    let _episode = Episode(id: episode.id, title: episode.title, comments: comments)
                    fullyEpisodes.append(_episode)
                    print("done")
                }
            })
            group.leave()
        }
        group.wait()
        group.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
            comletion(fullyEpisodes)
        })

    })
}
```

When I try to replace the comment load request by "print("something")" (not a new async task), Dispatch group is working.

Comment: Think you meant `grand-central-dispatch` not `greatest-common-divisor` ;)

Comment: @JacobKing : Oops! I set wrong tag. Thanks :D

Comment: Yeah, annoyingly, specifying a tag of gcd replaces it with "greatest-common-divisor" (even though there are far more questions on Stack Overflow about grand central dispatch than greatest common divisor). See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251143/1271826 or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165133/propose-significant-change-in-the-definition-of-gcd-tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your second example, (a) move `group.leave()` into the `load()` completion handler closure; and (b) remove the `group.wait()` altogether.

```
func loadComments(comletion: @escaping ([Episode]) -> Void){
    loadEpisodes(completion: {
        episodes in
        var fullyEpisodes = [Episode]()
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        for episode in episodes {
            group.enter()
            WebService().load(resource: episode.comment, comletion: {
                comments in
                if let comments = comments {
                    let _episode = Episode(id: episode.id, title: episode.title, comments: comments)
                    fullyEpisodes.append(_episode)
                    print("done")
                }
                group.leave()
            })
            // group.leave()
        }
        //group.wait()
        group.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
            comletion(fullyEpisodes)
        })

    })
}
```

or, cleaning that up a bit with trailing closure syntax and fixing `completion` spelling:

```
func loadComments(completion: @escaping ([Episode]) -> Void) {
    loadEpisodes { episodes in
        var fullyEpisodes = [Episode]()
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        for episode in episodes {
            group.enter()
            WebService().load(resource: episode.comment) { comments in
                if let comments = comments {
                    let _episode = Episode(id: episode.id, title: episode.title, comments: comments)
                    fullyEpisodes.append(_episode)
                }
                group.leave()
            }
        }
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            completion(fullyEpisodes)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited with your instruction. But I executed group.notify..( comletion(fullyEpisodes)) before to excute Webservice().load. @Rob

Comment: @Rob How can we synchronise the call backs. Let's assume `WebService().load` is making a async networking call. But the call backs are not synchronised. You might get the response of 2nd episode first and then the 1st episode. How can we make response in serial order. (1st episode response, then 2nd , 3rd ...). I don't want to use any variable or array.

Comment: You either wrap them in `Operation` subclass (doing the necessary `isExecuting` and `isFinished` handling/KVO) in which case you can add these to a serial queue and/or use dependencies between your operations, or use a promises library, such as PromiseKit.